# How to count recursion depth without passing a count argument in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter `n` and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in `n` until you reach a single digit.

For example:

I have tried this code which works but the game's rule is that I cannot pass 2 arguments. So I have to eliminate the `counter` argument.

```py
def persistence(n,counter): #recursion

    n = list(str(n))
    product = 1

    for i in n:
        product *= int(i)

    if product < 10:
        return counter+1

    else:
        counter +=1
        return persistence(product,counter)
```

```py
persistence(39) # returns 3, because 3*9=27, 2*7=14, 1*4=4
                 # and 4 has only one digit
```

Comment: Well, for starters, recursion isn't needed.  It's a simple iterative loop.  You should normally only use recursion when you genuinely need a stack, or if it significantly simplifies the coding.  But if you have to use recursion, don't pass `counter`, but instead return it.  You shouldn't need to know anything about your caller to know how many times your current invocation needs.  The caller then adds one and returns it.  Simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a default argument if you wanted to keep your algorithm the same:

```
def persistence(n, counter=0):
    product = 1

    for i in str(n):
        product *= int(i)

    if product < 10:
        return counter + 1

    return persistence(product, counter + 1)

print(persistence(39))
```

Having said that, as @TomKarzes points out, there's no need for the `counter` argument at all (or recursion for that matter)--pass the result back up the call stack rather than down. Any given call doesn't need any information from previous calls other than the current state of `n` itself to determine persistence.

```
def persistence(n):
    product = 1

    for i in str(n):
        product *= int(i)

    if product < 10:
        return 1

    return persistence(product) + 1

print(persistence(39))
```

Comment: Thanks. I just added an if statement in the case where the input is already a single digit number and should, therefore, return 1: `if len(n) == 1:
        return 0`